# How to compare two DateTime values in Flutter (dart) using IF condition?

Tags: java, android, flutter

how to Compare to DateTime value like Nowtime(10.13 pm) and Compare with future timelike (10:15 pm), these two-time compare in if Condition, this is true then perform task else showing Error

```
String formattedtime = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(DateTime.now());
//getting Current time is formattedtime
// time is stored in database and comapre with this
if(date==formattedDate &&formattedtime==time &&status =='false'){

}else{
     // else condition
 }

// remove time condition then working fine 

if(date==formattedDate&&status =='false'){

  // this condition working Fine but with Time Compare not working 

}else{
     // else condition
 }
```

not working

I don't know how to compare these result, I just want to if the current time is  greater then or equal to time(that's in a database)then perform the task

thanks

Comment: so you have two `DateTime` and you want to compare them?

Comment: I converted datetime in string and then campare

Comment: That's not right approach @Gnziet

Comment: It's campare with time not date like (10:30am) and 10:35 am how to compare in string value

Comment: what do you mean string comparison? why do you want to compare in that way?

Comment: Ok I understand this not a right way,I will do it with isbefore and isafter but I just want to know how to store time value in cloud firestore in DateTime

Comment: Please specify the right title because it is misleading

Answer (score 3):

Convert into `DateTime` and use `isAfter` or `isBefore` to compare

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.now();
System.out.println(date1);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.now().plusDays(1);
System.out.println(date2);
System.out.println(date1.isBefore(date2));     //true
System.out.println(date1.isAfter(date2));      //false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.jm();// this is the format like(5:08 PM)
 DateTime now =  DateTime.now();// current time 
 DateTime open = dateFormat.parse(time); // time is dynamic value database
 open = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, open.hour, open.minute);

 // here your condition

 if(now.isAfter(open)){
   // task here
  }else{
 }
```

Comment: No need for `new` these days.  Just makes it noisier.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the DateTime to millisecondsSinceEpoch values, and then compare the integer values